# Getting attention to a unanswered question

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

I have this chain of questions that got partially answered, partially solved by me, but ultimately unsolved till now. When a question gets old, it loses attention right? How can I make people look at the questions without re-posting as I have been blamed that I am doing?

Refer to this question to see the history (I can't link more than 1 link here due to low reputation)

[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889029/linker-question-again-closed)